# google sheets string.indexOf('string') not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to write a script that will copy rows from one sheet to other sheets based on the responses to certain columns. However I am running into problems with checking if a string var contains another string var.

```
function checkInterest(cell)
{
// assumes source data in sheet named Needed
// target sheet of move to named Acquired
// test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
s = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
r = s.getActiveRange();
i = s.getMaxRows();
v = lastValue('P'); 
addByInterest('Lighting','Lighting');
//addByInterest('Sound','Sound');
addHM();
}

function lastValue(column) {
var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + "1:" +  
column + lastRow).getValues();

for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
return values[lastRow - 1];
}

function addByInterest(interest,sheetName)
{
Logger.log(v);
Logger.log('Lighting, Sound'.indexOf('Lighting'));
Logger.log(v.indexOf(interest.valueOf()));
if(s.getName() == 'Form Responses 1' && 
(v.indexOf(interest.valueOf()) >= 0)){
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
}
}
function addHM()
{
Logger.log('RAN');
if(s.getName() == 'Form Responses 1' && 
 (v.indexOf('Hair') >= 0 || v.indexOf('Makeup') >= 0)){  
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hair & Makeup');
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
}
}
```

Logger prints

```
[15-10-01 12:14:27:346 EDT] [Lighting, Sound]
[15-10-01 12:14:27:346 EDT] Lighting
[15-10-01 12:14:27:347 EDT] 0.0
[15-10-01 12:14:27:348 EDT] -1.0 //Should return greater than or equal to 0
[15-10-01 12:14:27:349 EDT] RAN
```

I have tried with and without .valueOf() for the strings. Somewhat new to JS and completely new to Google Scripts so this may just be a simple fix but I'm not sure.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `valueOf()`.

`.getValues();`returns an array of arrays and you're targeting a specific child array with `return values[lastRow - 1];`, which is then assigned to `v` - based on the code you've shared.

Perhaps there's leading or trailing whitespace in the array values. When called on an array `indexOf()` looks for an exact match (whitespace would mess that up) vs `indexOf()` on a string will return the start position of the string you're trying to match:

```
[" foo"].indexOf("foo"); // returns -1 due to the leading whitespace
" foo".indexOf("foo"); // returns 1
```

Perhaps `v[0].indexOf()` will fix the issue.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thank you!